# Error when runing 'flutterfire configure': HTTP Error: 403, The caller does not have permission

Tags: flutter, firebase

On `flutterfire configure` command I am getting this error.
OS: Fedora 36

```
[debug] [2022-06-09T16:49:47.182Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] [2022-06-09T16:49:47.184Z] Command:       /usr/local/bin/firebase /home/virendra/.cache/firebase/tools/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/bin/firebase projects:create my-notes-vcarp --json
[debug] [2022-06-09T16:49:47.185Z] CLI Version:   11.0.1
[debug] [2022-06-09T16:49:47.185Z] Platform:      linux
[debug] [2022-06-09T16:49:47.185Z] Node Version:  v16.15.0
[debug] [2022-06-09T16:49:47.186Z] Time:          Thu Jun 09 2022 22:19:47 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
[debug] [2022-06-09T16:49:47.186Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
..
..
https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/my-notes-vcarp:addFirebase {"error":{"code":403,"message":"The caller does not have permission","status":"PERMISSION_DENIED"}}
[debug] [2022-06-09T16:50:00.272Z] HTTP Error: 403, The caller does not have permission
[debug] [2022-06-09T16:50:00.277Z] FirebaseError: HTTP Error: 403, The caller does not have permission
    at module.exports (/home/virendra/.cache/firebase/tools/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/responseToError.js:47:12)
    at RetryOperation._fn (/home/virendra/.cache/firebase/tools/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/apiv2.js:286:39)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
[error] 
[error] Error: Failed to add Firebase to Google Cloud Platform project. See firebase-debug.log for more info.
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a project first directly on Firebase and then select it from the CLI options. Most likely, Flutterfire does not have Firebase permissions.

Thanks to [Tomas Radvansky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12271773/tomas-radvansky) for their help.

Answer (score 0):

simply just run **firbase login:ci** to generate access key before you run flutterfire configure command.