# Constant error creating Firebase project via "flutterfire configure"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-storage

I have just installed flutterfire in order to create a new Firebase project with the "flutterfire configure" command. After executing this command I am getting the following error:

[Console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifTQx.png)

I looked at the content of the debug log and found this:

[Debug log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rntDh.png)

Any ideas about what should I do?

I have tried this with several names but that does not seem to be the problem.

Comment: The solution proposed by [Virendra Carpenter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19310908/virendra-carpenter) in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72568553/error-when-runing-flutterfire-configure-http-error-403-the-caller-does-not) post worked. Anyway, I still have the doubt about why flutterfire does not work.